# Swipe with touching yt iframe blocks webpage java-scripts on some iOS devices, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

I'm developing portal including some videos from yt, and run into problem which makes it unusable on some iOS devices. I simplified it for the purpose of this question.

I have simple web page with pasted iframe code obtained from youtube page share menu.
On some ios devices after scrolling or just swiping page so finger touches video other page javascripts stop working.

I have tried it with different videos and different iframe attributes sets, but I'm getting same behavior.

I came up with simple codepen https://codepen.io/Poziomka/pen/wvwjMZx (https://codepen.io/Poziomka/full/wvwjMZx - full screen) - it contains random video and button showing and hiding some text on click.

html

```
<section class="article__container">
    <h1 class="article__title">Ios iframe scroll bug</h1>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bltXlWpkDpg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>When you swipe touching the video on some ios, it blocks java script on the page</p>
    <button class="js-button">Show hiden text</button>
    <span class="article__text-to-toggle js-text">Text toggled by button</span>  
</section>
```

js

```
const text = document.querySelector(".js-text");
const button = document.querySelector(".js-button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    text.classList.toggle("article__text-to-toggle--visible");
});
```

In Safari on iPhoneSE with iOS 11.4.1, iPadMini with iOS 11.4, iPhone7 with iOS 12.2 after scrolling, so video was touched, button stops working, and i can't hide or show text anymore.
This problem doesn't occur in Safari on iPadAir with iOS 11.1.2.

While debugging this problem on browser stack on iPhone 7 iOS, v12 on page load sometimes I get error:
"Trying to call enumerateDevices from a frame without correct 'allow' attribute." but no additional error when button gets blocked. It seems related to the issue, but button blocks every time while error occurs only sometimes.

How to fix it?